# Linker script and data allocation

Tags: microcontroller, memory, bootloader, rom

I know that `.data` will be in the RAM, but I came across article that says during boot of an micro-controller the initial value of variables is stored in the ROM and then the boot-loader copy the initial values of variables from ROM to RAM, Is this true!?

Comment: Related: [What resides in the different memory types of a microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237740/what-resides-in-the-different-memory-types-of-a-microcontroller)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask yourself how could the system work if it isn't true?

In most implementations, the `.data` segment is for initialized data, where `.bss` is for data that is set to zero.  You can't count on RAM being set to anything at all on power-up, so the processor has to zero out the `.bss` segment and initialize `.data`.

Usually this is done by storing an image of the start-up value of the `.data` segment in ROM, and copying it to the correct location in RAM on startup.

Comment: the bootloader of laptops and computer also does the same thing!?

Comment: It is not the bootloader but the startup code of *every program* stored in ROM regardless of platform.

Comment: PC bootloaders are a considerably different animal.  The *BIOS* probably does it (most modern-day BIOS's are probably written in C), but the *bootload* process is multi-step, and the actual operating system comes from disk.  I suggest searching on some variation of "how does the PC bootload process work" if you want to study up on that one.

Comment: A modern BIOS is a bunch of *tens* of firmwares running on different components and loaded from some kind of ROMs at different stages. And yes most (if not all) of these are working this way.

Comment: @EugeneSh. so what does bootloader do in general !?, and doesn't startup code and bootloader is the same thing !?

Comment: No. A bootloader is a separate *program* which is running before the others and is intended to allow other programs to run. A startup code is a *part* of the same program, which is running *before* `main` (in C) and responsible for setting up the memory, stack and the data ad bss sections as explained for *this specific program*. Then it is calling `main`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That's how values of variables get initialized, and the rest of the variables are in .bss section which is normally cleared to zero on startup.

Comment: this also happens in big laptops an computer right !?

Comment: Yes if it is a program written in C language for example, C startup code initializes variables for you before main. If it is a program written in assembly, there is no startup code to do anything.

Comment: why in assembly there is no startup code?! How this operation works in assembly

Comment: Nobody forces you to do anything in assembly, you can write your startup if you like, or link the assembly with C startup. Feel free to look at how STM32 startup works for example. But this is now off topic for Electrical Engineering