# Efficient understanding of Hardware Software Interface in Embedded

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, interface, peripheral

I am a budding engineer in the embedded field. My work involves both the circuit design and software development of microcontrollers. So, I need to understand how the software is working on microcontroller architecture in depth.

For instance, enabling 1 bit in the software will fill the 1-bit memory in the microcontroller. How it is filled, in which section it will be filled?

This way, I need to understand all peripherals involved in microcontroller. What's the best way and source for my need? Help please!

Comment: This is a realy basic question and not easy to answear becaus it involves the complete development chain from compiling, linking and executing the source code on a device. I don't know in which year you are but you will probably learn this during your study. If this is not soon enough for you, check out microcontroller online classes on platforms like udemy, skillshare, udacity, ...

Comment: Datasheets, User Guides and Integration Manuals for the MCUs is a good place to start.

Comment: This is a good place to start: [What resides in the different memory types of a microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237740/what-resides-in-the-different-memory-types-of-a-microcontroller)

Comment: This question is too broad for this site. You need to focus the question and target a specific problem you face. Asking questions that require a book-length answers are off-topic. Focus.

Comment: I just asked from where to start?

Comment: Start from Google. Google books on an embedded systems, embedded software, embedded C, 8051, PIC, AVR, ARM. Read, nurture. Thousand of resources and books. Closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you work from the basics up. Trying to understand a complex subject from the top down becomes difficult. If you begin with the basics of digital logic and work up to the design of computing machines, the answers to your question and many others become self evident. It is not particularly difficult - the maths is minimal and suitable for early teens to grasp. There are many standard textbooks and online learning resources.
Whilst I have not watched much of this, Ben Eater has a number of Youtube videos where he explains many fundamental topics with examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check on it. Other than videos, can you suggest some books in embedded field for fundamental topics?